# What makes this hashing function injective?

Tags: java, hash

Can somebody with a better understanding of hashing techniques please explain to me: what makes the function below an injective hashing function?

This function below is supposedly producing a unique hash key for a Search tree that:

-contains only values between 1 and 99 and

-contains every possible int not more than once

Is it really necessary to choose 100 as a multiplier (i assume the idea being that 100 is not in the range of possible tree-values)?

Wouldn't a prime number like 31 for example also reliably produce the expected output?

```
int injectiveHashFunc(Tree b){
    int[] po = postorder-tree-walk(b);
    int key = 0;
    for(k = 0; k < po.length; k++) {
        key = key * 100 + po[k];
    }
    return key;
}
```

Comment: What do you get when you multiply any number with 100 and add a two-digit number? (if it is a one-digit number like 0-9 doesn't actually matter in this case)  ... that doesn't do more than just "appending" `k` to `key`.

Comment: wow!! Thank you! that is true and I can't believe I didn't realize that.  it makes the hash just all the values appended into one long number! So simple. Amazing!